# saving data from csv to php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, csv

I am trying to import all the data from csv to the database.
Below code is ajax request that is sent to a php file.

```
$('#upload_location_csv').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var queryDict = {};
    location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]});
    fi = document.getElementById("csv_file_input").files[0];
    reader = new FileReader;
    reader.onload = function(){
        csv_data = reader.result;
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:ajax_root_path+'fend.php',
            data:{
                location_id:queryDict['id'],
                csv_data:csv_data,
                perform_action:"save_delivery_csv_data"
            },
            success:function(resObj){
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error:function(resObj){

            }

        });
    };
    reader.readAsText(fi);

});
```

This is the action that is performed, where here is, `save_delivery_csv_data` .

When I click on import csv, the page reloads and no request is sent to fend.php.

```
case 'save_delivery_csv_data':
    {
        $location_id = $param_array['location_id'];
        $csv_data = $param_array['csv_data'];       
        $csv_data_rows  =   explode("\n",$csv_data);
        unset($csv_data_rows[0]);
        $csv_data_rows = array_values($csv_data_rows);
        debug($csv_data_rows);
        $csv_data_array = array();
        foreach ($csv_data_rows as $csv_row_key => $csv_row_value)
        {
            $csv_row_value_array    =   explode(",",$csv_row_value);
            debug($csv_row_value_array);
            if(count($csv_row_value_array) == 5)
            {   
                /*$csv_data_array[$csv_row_key] = array();
                $csv_data_array[$csv_row_key]['locality_id']    =   $csv_row_value_array[0];
                $csv_data_array[$csv_row_key]['locality_name']  =   $csv_row_value_array[1];
                $csv_data_array[$csv_row_key]['minimum_order_amount']   =   $csv_row_value_array[2];
                $csv_data_array[$csv_row_key]['delivery_time']  =   $csv_row_value_array[3];
                $csv_data_array[$csv_row_key]['delivery_charge']    =   $csv_row_value_array[4];*/
                //debug($csv_row_value_array);
                if(isset_empty($csv_row_value_array[3]))
                {
                    //debug($csv_row_value_array);

                    $locality_id =  $csv_row_value_array[0];


                    $location_outletValues = array();
                    $location_outletValues['cloud_site_id']         =   $cloud_site_id;
                    $location_outletValues['location_id']           =   $location_id;
                    $location_outletValues['locality_id']           =   $locality_id;
                    $location_outletValues['minimum_order']         =   $csv_row_value_array[2];
                    $location_outletValues['delivery_time']         =   $csv_row_value_array[3];
                    $location_outletValues['delivery_charge']       =   $csv_row_value_array[4];

                    $sql = "SELECT outlet_locality_id FROM ".PLATFORM_OUTLET_LOCALITIES."
                            WHERE location_id='".$location_id."' AND locality_id='".$locality_id."'";
                    $outlet_locality_array      =   $DB->query($sql);
                    //debug($outlet_locality_array);
                    if(count($outlet_locality_array) > 0)
                    {
                        $condition_array = array();
                        $condition_array['outlet_locality_id']  =   $outlet_locality_array[0]->outlet_locality_id;
                        //debug($condition_array);
                        debug($location_outletValues);
                        $DB->update(PLATFORM_OUTLET_LOCALITIES,$location_outletValues,$condition_array);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $DB->insert(PLATFORM_OUTLET_LOCALITIES,$location_outletValues);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        break;
        //debug($csv_data_array);
    }
```

What am I missing out here?? I also tried debugging variables values, but no request was sent to fend.php, whereas other request on the same page are being successfully sent.

Comment: unrelated, but important: you're vulnerable to injection attacks. Please use prepared statements ASAP

Comment: check whether by removing  `csv_data:csv_data` in ajax call to fend.php executed or not ??

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Yes, I know. Data is not a crucial data so there was no necessity for PDO.

Comment: @AtulNar One of the main problem is that page reloads and I can't see what does fend.php sends.

Comment: @NikhileshVaishy: Prepared statements aren't a `PDO` thing. They're vital for security, and are a DB feature. `PDO` and `mysqli` both offer an API that use prepared statements. It's not about vital data or no, it's about basic security. Also: if you're not using `PDO` or `mysqli`, there **is** a need to switch, because `mysql_*` is ***deprecated***

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Yes I understand, we are using prepared statements where necessary. Right now my problem is something different. If you could help me on this, it would of great help

Comment: @NikhileshVaishy: You don't seem to understand that having a vulnerable query ***is*** a big problem, even if the data is not critical/sensitive. It's lazy, and a security issue. I'm not going to help you fix a bug in code that is fundamentally flawed.